# Is there a python function or library to determine whether a given string is a postgresql-valid datetime?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a list of strings. Some of them can be successfully entered into a postgres table as valid datetime values; some are invalid. I want to separate them out in python - is there a library function that can do this? I would even be happy to see postgresql's underlying functionality that determines whether a string is a valid datetime so that I can build the python function myself. This is especially needed because postgresql seems to have arbitrary rules on what constitutes a valid date - for example, '5-31,2019' is not valid while '5,31-2019' is.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the end? If you just want to prep the data for adding it to a database, you might want to try `python-dateutil` and `datetime`

Comment: Do the str -> datetime conversion functions have the same specification as postgres-valid datetimes? If not, that isn't quite what I need

Answer (score 0):

The Postgres date routines ALL produce valid dates. The conversion routines also produce valid dates given sufficient information. If you intentionally use non-standard formats and try to find strings that fail to convert representations you can always do so. In your examples one string happened to match the default settings for converting ambiguous strings while the other didn't. You do not have to rely on the default; you can tell Postgres the how to interpret the string to be converted using format specification of the the to_date function. Doing so both your examples convert to a the same valid date.

```
select  to_date('5-31,2019','mm-dd,yyyy') 
union all
select  to_date('5,31-2019','mm,dd-yyyy');
```